# Cleaning pdf files by hand and removing hyperref visible links

Tags: hyperref

I sometimes need to "clean" pdf files produced by LateX. I do this using Adobe Acrobat Pro. Unfortunately, the well-known hyperref links (small red or green boxes mainly around equation numbers or citations) do not seem to be easily removable. Do you know which kind of pdf objects they are?

Comment: Er, why would you clean the PDF rather than changing the source and recompiling it?

Comment: @cfr hihi, here please assume that I do not have the source files.

Comment: Then ask the author to make the change. I could see why you might occasionally need to do this for some weird set of circumstances, but you are describing it as a regular thing and that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just found two ways (in Acrobat Pro 11):

1. Tools -> Protection -> Sanitize Document (this will erase all boxes and more at once)
2. Tools -> Content Editing -> Add or Edit Link (to edit the boxes one by one)

It seems to me that these hyperref objects are "links" for Acrobat Pro: this is quite obvious after all.